# A simple enqueue/dequeue not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

WP Guru's,

I am testing the enqueue/dequeue because in my child theme, I am trying to override an enqueued script block from the parent theme.

Maybe I'm doing it all wrong but I added this block of code in the top of my [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)'s functions.php. I expect not to see that that echo'ed statement but I do.

I moved the priority attribute up and down with no joy. It should be pretty straight forward unless I'm going about it all wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sometest', 90);
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'undo_it',80);

function sometest() {
        echo '****** IF YOU SEE ME THEN ITS NOT WORKING *****************';
}
function undo_it() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'sometest' );
   wp_deregister_script( 'sometest' ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% percent sure what you're trying to accomplish here. The code you run in `undo_it` will have no effect on the `echo` in `sometest`. `wp_enqueue_script` and related functions are for injecting JavaScript files into the page, not modifying hooked PHP functions.

You might be looking for the `remove_action` function instead.

Comment: remove_action is indeed what I needed.  Thanks for the hint in the right direction. Also it's worth noting that:

1) In a child theme it only worked inside a add_action.
2) priority must be exactly the same as the original add_action that you are trying to remove.


`function unhook_action() {
 remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'method_name', exact_prioirity);
}
add_action('init','unhook_action');
`

Comment: Happy to help. Keep in mind that you can only remove an action after it's been added. That's why you needed to hook your `unhook_actions` function.

Comment: Or maybe don't use `wp_enqueue_scripts` because you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Wyck, what's wrong with removing an action that you don't want to run? Isn't that exactly the type of modification child themes are for?

Comment: @Wyck unfortunately I am overriding in a child theme what another developer had already done in a parent theme. Editing the original functions.php is not an option.

Comment: The equeue script functions are meant to organize and prevent conflicts with javascript (and to some extend CSS), so you're meant to use the `$handle` since no one wants for example `jQuery` loaded 10 times on a page. If the parent theme is poorly coded than I guess you have no option.

Comment: Of course, if all @Ash wanted to do was prevent a js file from loading, he could use `wp_dequeue_script`, but from the question, it seemed like he was trying to unhook a PHP function. The right way to do that is with remove_action.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to test with an actual script and not an `echo`. The main problem is that `wp_dequeue_script` and `wp_deregister_script` take a `$handle` as an argument and not a function name.

For example:

```
function de_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

`jquery` in this case is a `$handle` that has been used in `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_register_script`

This is all written in the codex for these functions.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

If the parent theme is not using `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_register_script` with a `$handle` then they are ***doing it wrong***.